# How do PSIM z-blocks and s-blocks + ZOH work? MATLAB and PSIM results not matching

Tags: simulation, transfer-function, pid-controller, matlab, digital-filter

I've just came across PSIM's digital control and C blocks. My main goal is, in the future, to implement a dynamic control with C block in PSIM.

I created the circuit below and it runs:

[image]

The circuit attempts to make a switching MOSFET logic for power electronics applications (DC motor driving.)  The point is, because of not knowing my real-world motor parameters (only its TF,) I just can't make use of the PSIM DC motor schematic model.

As an alternative, I used a TF s-block. The transfer function (Iout/Vin) was experimentally obtained in the lab for a DC motor and is as follows.

[image]

The question is: What is the PSIM logic for digital blocks? My simulation result don't match with the MATLAB one and I'm going nuts.

[image]

The MATLAB settling time is something like 1 sec and the overshoot ~1600%. The MATLAB results match the osciloscope (oscilloscope + current transducter LEM la55)  for my real-world micromotor.

What does it happen? Moreover, shouldn't it result in a simulation with a switched pattern? Once it's using the MOSFET switch (10kHz 50% duty cycle), shouldn't Vout be something toggle on/off?

As I said I was impressed by PSIMs TF's possibilities and it may be very useful soon, but I really need to master its resources.

---

Edited: I realized what the mistakes were. Now I implemented the circuit below, everything set to 10kHz and with DACin=0xFF (reference = 1V).
[image]

Despite having corrected the schematic, now suit, It's now even more akward. The closed loop (unitary feedback) z- TF is as follows:

[image]

Then the results, a step response with a lot of oscilation and with akward characteristics.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a PSIM forum?

Comment: You seem to want to create a power switching source but the MOSFET, even if it's an ideal one, does not have a load on its source to GND? Also a ZOH is implied to model the bridge from discrete (sampled) to continuous time domain brought by a DAC. What is its purpose here? I would recommend that you first convert your \$s\$-domain motor TF into the \$z\$-domain and carry on with control in the discrete-time domain.

Comment: Ty all for the answers. @VerbalKint, I dont understand very well the ZOH purpose, I just followed a tutorial, that would use it. 
I tried to use a z-block instead of a s. The z Tf is num=[676,-676] and den=[1,-1] but in this case the output gets unstable (dkwhy).
Another test that i made was to take out the switch and resimulate. But akwardly ,the result was the same of having the MOSFET there.

Comment: Verbal, Im sorry for the long while before I understand what u suggested! Now I realized what u were talking about. I tryied to reproduce your ideia, that is, the DAC as a digital source. But please, I still need guidance because the PSIM results keep not matching the reality (see my edited question pls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PSIM digital elements execute at the rate assigned to them and are z-domain. if you want to model an s-domain transfer function there should be no ZOH blocks in series with them.

A typical issue with digital control is that many people forget to implement digital delay.

For your motor model, you have a s-domain transfer function.

I am happy to help answer your questions, more in depth please head on over to the new  official PSIM forum through Altair's community.

Comment: Thanks !  I got around the problem, I had a hard time and insisted a lot on the issue. The big trouble is the lack of documentation and YouTube tutorials. But I think psim is a great tool, I like it better, even than Simulink, Matlab...